# Proving origin to be removable singularity(Proof verification)

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity

This particular question is from Ponnusamy Silvermann complex section 9.22 ( question no. 2) and I am unable to solve it.

> Let f(z) be analytic in deleted neighborhood of origin and lim $z\to 0$ | zf(z) |=0 . Then show that origin is removable singularity of f(z).

I need to show that lim $z\to 0 f(z) $=M(finite) . But if it were infinite, then  $z \to z_0$ |zf(z) | would be indeterminate.

So, it's removable.

Is my proof correct?

Comment: The argument you present is far from being correct, as it seems to assume that a limit of a complex valued functions is either finite or infinite (which also brings up the question exactly what kind of infinity are you referring to in $\mathbb{C}$?), whereas there is also the possibility that the limit doesn't exist. What you should do instead is consider the function $g \colon U \setminus \{0\} \to \mathbb{C}$ given by $g(z)=zf(z)$ and argue that it extends by continuity to a holomorphic function $h$ on $U$, whose order at $0$ is $1$ (*to be cont.*)

Comment: (*cont.*) such that you can write $h(z)=zk(z)$ for a holomorphic function $k \colon U \to \mathbb{C}$. It will then follow that $k$ is a (actually the *unique*) holomorphic extension of $f$ to $U$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From $$\lim_{z\to 0}zf(z)=0,$$
we know than $z=0$ is  removable singularity of  $F(z):=zf(z)$.
Define $F(0)=0$, then $F$ is analytic at $z=0$, and its Taylor series of $F$ at $z=0$ is
$$F(z)=zf(z)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_nz^n,$$
($a_0=0$ is due to $F(0)=0$).
So the Taylor series of $f$ at $z=0$ is
$$f(z)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_nz^{n-1},$$
hence, $$\lim_{z\to 0}f(z)=a_1.$$
So the origin is removable singularity of $f(z)$.

Answer (score 0):

A counterexample for your proof would be $f(z)=1/\sqrt{z}$. I think you need to use the property of analyticity in some way to exclude such cases.

Comment: The functions such as you suggest -- and which do not constitute a counterexample for the above attempt at a proof (which is incorrect, but that is an issue for the poster to worry over) -- are automatically prevented by the hypothesis on the domain of definition: a punctured neighourhood of the origin. No such punctured neighbourhood admits the existence of branches of logarithms defined on it, for reasons of residues...

Comment: That was my point. The requirement of analyticity is necessary but was not used in the proof, hence it is missing something. But you are right, "counterexample" probably is the wrong word here.

Comment: In that case, your point does not seem to be properly conveyed. My contention is that given a setting where one considers an $f$ already specified as defined on a punctured neighbourhood of the origin it doesn't make sense to say ''a counterexample could be $f(z)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{z}}$, for the simple reason that you can't define such a branch of the radical on such a punctured neighbourhood!